# Various Odd Errors in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, compiler-errors

In Xcode, I am getting some various odd errors that should build normally.

First, In

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent(UIEvent *)event {
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    marblebeingdragged = NO;
}
```

it gives me the errors:

```
error: Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'touchesMoved'
in the first line: `expected ';' before ':' token`
```

Also, in my switch statement: (Note the errors that are commented in the case and break statements)

```
switch (marblecolor) {    
    case 1: //Aqua
        plusone.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Aqua/+1"]; //Parse Issue: Extraneous ']' before ';'

        plustwo.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Aqua/+2"];
        plusthree.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Aqua/+3"];
        minusone.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Aqua/-1"];
        minustwo.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Aqua/-2"];
        minusthree.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Aqua/-3"];
            break; //Semantic Issue: 'break' statement not in loop or switch statement

    case 2: //Blue //Semantic Issue: 'case' statement not in switch statement
        plusone.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blue/+1"];
        plustwo.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blue/+2"];
        plusthree.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blue/+3"];
        minusone.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blue/-1"];
        minustwo.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blue/-2"];
        minusthree.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blue/-3"];
        break; //Semantic Issue: 'break' statement not in loop or switch statement

    case 3: //Green //Semantic Issue: 'case' statement not in switch statement
        plusone.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Green/+1"];
        plustwo.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Green/+2"];
        plusthree.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Green/+3"];
        minusone.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Green/-1"];
        minustwo.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Green/-2"];
        minusthree.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Green/-3"];
            break; //Semantic Issue: 'break' statement not in loop or switch statement

    case 4: //Semantic Issue: 'case' statement not in switch statement
        plusone.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Grey/+1"];
        plustwo.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Grey/+2"];
        plusthree.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Grey/+3"];
        minusone.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Grey/-1"];
        minustwo.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Grey/-2"];
        minusthree.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Grey/-3"];
            break; //Semantic Issue: 'break' statement not in loop or switch statement

    case 5: //Pink //Semantic Issue: 'case' statement not in switch statement
        plusone.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Pink/+1"];
        plustwo.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Pink/+2"];
        plusthree.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Pink/+3"];
        minusone.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Pink/-1"];
        minustwo.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Pink/-2"];
        minusthree.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Pink/-3"];
            break;
}
```

Lastly, in my `@end` it gives the error: `expected declaration or statement at end of input`.

Any clues to the errors?

Answer (score 4):

For starters, your `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent(UIEvent *)event {` line needs a colon after `withEvent`, so it should be `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {`.

Fix that and we'll see what works. (EDIT: Looking at your other errors, they may go away after you've fixed the method declaration typo. I would certainly expect the `@end` error to go away.)

Comment: Treat the first error(s) it encounters before moving on to others. Often any errors after the first are caused because it can't make sense of the rest.

Comment: Noticed Something- Xcode 4's Auto-Completion does not auto-complete that line like it used to. . .

Comment: @Ahan You get the same errors even after adding the colon? That should at least fix that error, probably the `@end` error, too.

Comment: @CajunLuke, I get the same errors, but now for touchesMoved, it tells me `'touchesMoved' undeclared (first use in this function)` This keeps on getting more puzzling by the hour!!

Comment: @Ahan Is the method signature in the header file? `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`

Comment: @CajunLuke - It is not, I have never put that there before. Can you please explain

Comment: @Ahan You should put signatures for all methods in the header. It is the only way for other classes to know what methods they can call on your class. Further, any method declared above another method in the implementation file won't "know" about the lower method unless the other method is declared in the header.

Comment: @CajunLuke Can you please post the code! Also,Should I declare my touchesBegan and touchesEnded?

Comment: @Ahan I put the signature in my comment above (`- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`). It's the same as the start of the method implementation, but with a semicolon instead of curly braces. Declare either a) any method that gives you that "<methodname> undeclared (first use in this function)" error, b) you implement in your class, or both. I declare all my methods in the header. Some people only declare "public" (API) methods. Some people only declare methods that annoy them. It's really a matter of taste unless you have a corporate style guide.

Comment: @CajunLuke Exactly, where do I declare this? When I declare it among my actions in my .h, it has no effect.

Comment: @Ahan Declare it in between the `@interface` and `@end` in the class header, and make sure you import the header in whatever files are complaining.

Comment: @CajunLuke Figured it out, something with Xcode, When I removed all those, the `-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` started doing the same thing. So, Just copied the code individually to a new Xcode project and it works!!